# can we resize WP_LIST_TABLE column size?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wp_list_table class in my plugin,I am getting data and display it on admin side using wp_list_table.But one column has too much large data and its length is too long which dosen't looks good.so is there any way to increase length of column,I tried using apply direct class css but dosent effect.Because its wordpress's own class.
I search on google much but no one has same problem.
please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes man, you can use the "Screen options" in case of not to display unnecessary columns for sometimes.

Secondly you may apply this css code for redesign the columns ...

```
function admin_header() {
$page = ( isset($_GET['page'] ) ) ? esc_attr( $_GET['page'] ) : false;
if( 'my_list_test' != $page )
return; 

echo '<style type="text/css">';
echo '.wp-list-table .column-id { width: 5%; }';
echo '.wp-list-table .column-booktitle { width: 40%; }';
echo '.wp-list-table .column-author { width: 35%; }';
echo '.wp-list-table .column-isbn { width: 20%; }';
echo '</style>';
}
```